# How to present viewcontroller in fullscreen on ipad

Tags: ios, swift, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

I have a view controller , I can present it modally with full screen on iPhone but It's not becoming fullscreen on ipad. ( Its a small screen centered on iPad )

```
    iVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    iVC.presentFullScreen(myVC, animated: true)
```

I tried

```
iVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
```

Any ideas please

Comment: What are the guys named iVC and mVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view controller whose `modalPresentationStyle` needs to be `.fullScreen` is `myVC`, not `iVC`.